# Next Page Token

Tags: google-api, analytics, google-api-php-client

I have a php program that must read analytics data and save these data to a DB. Because the data is too big, I use the pagination (10000 to be more specific). As I run the code over and over again, sometimes I get the next page token, sometimes not. The problems it is a one-time-run program. I wonder what I'm doing wrong, here's the code:

```
do {
    $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($token);
    $data = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    $token = $data->reports[0]->getNextPageToken();
    $this->printResults($data);
} while ( $token != '' );
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is? If you make a request and the results fill your first response a PageToken won't be returned.

Comment: What I meant was in my attempts, the first batchGet sometimes returns nextPageToken, sometimes not. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, I need to get a full report for Sales Performance. I know there are over 100000 entries, but I keep getting 800. Was this understandable? Sorry anything, It's a job to be done ASAP

Comment: I would say that if you're only returning 800 when you expect more there is probably an issue with the parameters in the API call. Speaking of which, what API are you using?

Comment: Ok, I just found the problem, indeed it was me. Actually there are only 800 data, I don't understand much of analytic. Just found you're right, the parameters I pass for this search only match 800. The problem was I just went to sales performance and looked at the maximum result, without filtering, now by doing that I see the same amount returns. Thank you very much and apologies again

Comment: By the way, I am using the php sdk they provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The searching result was right, [ScottMcC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844376/scottmcc). I don't understand about analytics, so I forgot to filter in the sales report and check the results there are the same in the api return.